# Combine button look with focused color

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I have 2 xml files:
The first one changes the color when you are focusing the button and press it:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
      <solid android:color="#318e3e" />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape>
      <solid android:color="#318e3e" />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item>
    <shape>
      <solid android:color="#24c139" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

And the second one just changes the look of the button:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="#28bf3c" />
  <stroke android:width="1.5dp" android:color="#000000"/>
  <corners android:radius="25dp"/>


  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
      <solid android:color="#1b7196" />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape>
      <solid android:color="#1b7196" />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item>
    <shape>
      <solid android:color="#28bf3c" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</shape>
```

But how can I combine these 2 files into one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do like this in one xml(the color according to your needs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_window_focused="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="25dp" />
      <solid android:color="#24c139" />
      <stroke android:width="1.5dp" android:color="#000" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="25dp" />
      <solid android:color="#318e3e" />
      <stroke android:width="1.5dp" android:color="#000" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```